# can't install TotalCross plugin on macOS Big sur

Tags: java, macos, maven, homebrew

got this error, when using maven3.6.3 Failed to execute goal com.totalcross:totalcross-maven-plugin:2.0.2:retrolambda (post-compile) on project HelloTotalCross: Unable to execute mojo: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/nosakharedanielahanor/Library/Application Support/TotalCross/zulu_jdk_11/zulu-11.jre/Contents/Home/bin/java": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently the path for the java executable inside the Zulu JDK 11 changed since the release of the version 2.0.2 of the plugin.

update your pom to use 2.0.3 and it worked.